# Why do we need affine independence in the definition of a simplex?

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology, affine-geometry

So we can think of forming an $m$-simplex in $\mathbb{R}^n$ by taking $m+1$ affinely independent points in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and then taking all convex combinations of them.

Here is a more formal definiton.

[image]

Now I can (sort of) visually see why we need the convexity condition. If simplices were invented to be triangles and tetrahedra in higher dimensions, we don't want our simplices to not be convex.

The best reason why I can come up with as to why we need our $m+1$ points to be affinely independent, is that since $m$ of those point will end up to be linearly independent (by definition of affine independence), when we take convex combinations (which are just special linear combinations) of those $m+1$ points, $m$ of those points being linearly independent will generate something that looks like an $m$-dimensional vector subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$ but isn't quite a vector space at all, I suppose that it would generate a $m$-dimensional topological manifold (with boundary).

Like for example consider the $2$-simplex $[(0, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1)]$ this gives a triangle in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and linear independence of $(1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$ ensures that we get something that's not just a line, but is two-dimensional when we take convex combinations of those points.

Am I correct in saying then that the affine independence condition is needed so that our notion of dimension for simplices corresponds with the topological manifold dimension if we view the simplices as a topological manifold (with boundary)?

Comment: I think the reason for requiring affine independence is that you want the simplex to have full dimension, not live in a flat of lower dimension. The convexity isn't what's driving this part of the definition.

Comment: The short answer is Yes.  The uniqueness of barycentric coordinates (given an ordering of the vertices), as in copper.hat's answer, is important; but even without that, the convex hull of a set of $m+1$ points in $\mathbf{R}^n$ is $m$-dimensional if and only if the points are affinely independent.

Comment: In the definition that you quoted, if you removed the "affine independent" requirement and allowed just *any* $m$ points in $\mathbb R^n$, then, for example, every polygon in the plane $\mathbb R^2$ would count as a simplex --- just take $p_0,\dots,p_m$ to be the vertices  of your polygon. Similarly, all polyhedra in higher  dimensional spaces would count as simplices.

Comment: @EthanBolker By dimension though I'm assuming that you mean the topological manifold dimension of the simplex, since we can't really talk about any other notion of dimension (I know we can define the dimension of the simplex in a certain way, but that definition leads to the result that the simplex dimension agrees with its dimension as a topological manifold)

Comment: @Perturbative The simplex is an essentially linear object in real $n$ space so any reasonable definition of its dimension will be the dimension of the smallest Euclidean flat containing it. Affine independence implies that's the whole space Thinking of it as a manifold isn't usually useful since it has lots of corners.  But if you must, it's full dimension that way too.

Comment: I might (**very** loosely) suggest that the simplex, per se, is not the goal when dealing with manifolds, the idea is that the simplex represents a particular axes configuration based at an arbitrary point (as opposed to the $x-y-z$ based at the origin). Affine independence is essentially linear independence with respect to the basis formed by translating the simplex so that one of the vertices is at the origin.

Answer (score 1):

The point of affine independence is, as with linear independence, to ensure that the
representation of points in the affine hull is unique.

Some rambling follows in case it may be useful.

The affine hull of a set $P$ is the smallest affine set containing $P$. Alternatively,
$\operatorname{aff} P = \{ \sum_k \lambda_k p_k | \sum_k \lambda = 1, p_k \in P\} $, where the sums are finite.

(In the following, I implicitly assume that $\sum_k \lambda_k = 1$.)

If $x =\sum_k \lambda_k p_k\in \operatorname{aff} P$, the $\lambda_k$ are called the barycentric coordinates. They are not necessarily unique, for example, with $P=\{-1,0,1\}$ we can write $0 = 1 \cdot 0 = {1\over 2}  \cdot (-1) + {1\over 2} \cdot 1$.

As with linear spaces, it is convenient if the coordinates are unique, if $P$ is affinely independent, then the (barycentric) coordinates are unique.

Note that $x \in \operatorname{co} P $ if there are barycentric non negative coordinates such that $x = \sum_k \lambda_k p_k$. If $P$ is affinely independent, then we can state that $x \in \operatorname{co} P $ **iff** the barycentric  coordinates are non negative.

Note that in $\mathbb{R}^n$ there are at most $n+1$ linearly independent points (cf. Carathéodory's theorem)